# Regression sum of squares inequality

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Let $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is multivariate normal with mean of $0$ and variance of $\sigma^2 I$.

Suppose $X = (X_1\ \ X_2)$, and correspondingly, $\beta = (\beta_1\ \ \beta_2)$. Let $\hat{\beta}$ be the OLS estimate of $\beta$. Also, $\|Y\|$ is the Euclidean norm of $Y$, not that it makes a huge difference.

If $X_1,\ X_2$ are orthogonal, then prove the following inequality:

$$\|Y - X_1\hat{\beta}_1\|^2 + \|Y - X_2\hat{\beta}_2\|^2 \geq \|Y - X\hat{\beta}\|^2$$

Here is my progress:

Let $H$ be the hat matrix. Then from triangular inequality:

\begin{align}
& \|Y - X_1\hat{\beta}_1\|^2 + \|Y - X_2\hat{\beta}_2\|^2 \\
\geq {} & \|2Y - X_1\hat{\beta}_1-X_2\hat{\beta}_2\|^2 \\
= {} & \|2Y - X\hat{\beta}\|^2 \text{ since } \hat{\beta}^T = (\hat{\beta}^T_1\ \ \hat{\beta}^T_2) \\
= {} & \|2Y-HY\|^2 \\
= {} & \|(2I-H)Y\|^2
\end{align}

I don't know how I can justify $\|(2I-H)\|^2 \geq \|I-H\|^2$.

Am I on the right track? If so, how should I justify the last inequality? If I am not on the right track, please guide me to the right track! Thanks!

Comment: HY should just be H in line 4

Comment: Why is that? I had $HY$ because $X\hat{\beta} = X (X^TX)^{-1}X^T Y = HY$

Answer (score 1):

$||(2I - H)Y||^2 = ||[I + (I-H)]Y||^2 = ||Y + (I-H)Y||^2 = ||Y + \hat{\epsilon}||^2 \geq ||\hat{\epsilon}||^2 = ||(I-H)Y||^2$

?